# Java fill a two-dimensional table?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create x number of arrays with some characters (like 8478329478 for example). Now how do i do that?

That's the piece of code i wrote

```
char [] [] consequenceList = new char [xNumber] [10];
for (int i = 0; i < xNumber; i++) { 

    consequenceList[i] [] = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();

}
```

This is not working

DN.java:19: error: illegal start of expression

The error is pointing on the second [] after "consequenceList".

What am i doing wrong, or how could i do what i am trying to do?

Comment: you should generally avoid 2d arrays, they are often an indication that there are things you can still abstract out

Comment: `consequenceList[i] [] =` doesn't need that last `[]`. 2D array is simply array of arrays.

Comment: @MrD I've never heard anything about avoiding 2D arrays before. Can you elaborate a bit more please? Is it because of performance reasons? how can you abstract something that is naturally a 2D array for example?

Comment: 2d arrays can be avoided by creating classes with simple properties. For instance you can have a 2d array with the first dimension representing garages and the second representing cars but you could just as well have created a garage class with a list of cars in it and have a much more manageable abstraction at hand that is also easier to understand and read. People often avoid creating small classes because they think its an overkill and every class requires a bunch of boilerplate in java but it isn't significantly less performing and it's much better to work with

Answer (score 0):

## The Solution

Change

```
char[][] consequenceList = new char[xNumber][10];
```

to

```
char[][] consequenceList = new char[xNumber][];
```

---

And then change

```
consequenceList[i][] = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
```

to

```
consequenceList[i] = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
```

---

## The Explanation

In Java, a primitive array is an object in its own right.  (it even extends `Object`)  Therefore, a 2-d array in Java is an array object of array objects.  Since it is not necessary to supply a value for every element of an array at instantiation time, neither is it necessary to create an array object for every element of the top-level array at instantiation time.

Thus, the syntax `<type>[][] <identifier> = new <type>[<N>][];` creates a 2-d array of `N` elements at the top-level, but does not actually populate any of those elements with a second-level array yet.

This is useful because `sc.nextLine().toCharArray()` returns an entire array object.  So what you want to do is assign the return value of `sc.nextLine().toCharArray()` to a single element in your top-level array *(rather than having to copy its elements into a pre-existing second-level array)*.

And the way you access a single element in the top-level array of a multi-dimensional array is exactly the same way you would access a single element in a single-dimensional array.  This is why the assignment statement uses `consequenceList[i]` even though the declaration was `consequenceList[i][]`.